# Как убрать в версии пакета для composer dev в конце

Tags: php, git, composer, gitlab

Положил в закрытый репозиторий модуль и создал ветку 1.0. Когда через composer устанавливаю (из gitlab репозитория), мне предалагают только 1.0.x-dev. Как сделать так, чтобы не было постфикса?

Comment: Отредактируйте файл composer.json  Например:    "require": {
        "intervention/image": "^2.7"  Посмотрите https://habr.com/ru/post/439200/  - Версионирование